# How to continue downloads in ubuntu in firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, internet, download

I'm currently using Ubuntu 9.10, because I get higher download rates when I use this OS.
But the download rate is not consistent. How can I save the current download, because when I do it in XP, a pop-up would show if I want to save and quit. But in Ubuntu there is no such pop-up, is there any manual way on how to save the download and continue it on next startup?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/201) which is a very powerful Download-Manager, which does support up to 10 connections per download (maxing out your internet connection) and of course pausing/resume.

Comment: Seconded, been using this for ages. Fantastic add-in